# Avoiding Lua Callback Hell

Tags: callback, lua, coronasdk

I work a lot with Lua and Corona SDK, and while I love it as a language, I've realised that my code can get quite messy as callbacks call callbacks and so on.

I was wondering if there were any design patterns or libraries (like async.js for JavsScript) that help reduce the issue.

A typical example would be the use for Corona's transition call:

```
transition.to(obj,{... onComplete=function()
    transition.to(obj,{... onComplete=function()
        if foo then
            transition.to(obj,{... onComplete=function() ... end})
        else
            transition.to(obj,{... onComplete=function() ... end})
        end
    end})
end})
```

I find that code quickly become quite dense, but that often inner closures rely on variables from the outer ones. I appreciate that self-discipline is an important factor in creating clean code, but it's useful to have a structure to impose using self-discipline. Other than naming closures has anyone come across a useful way of managing this?

Comment: Just declare the object at the starting of desired scene, make the transition as a function (if they are same), and call the function whenever needed...

Comment: Is your problem performance or just coding style? If it's performance, you can't really do much about it, since that's the way Corona SDK works.

Comment: Coroutines can probably do the job here

Comment: My issue is more coding style than anything else. Like nested if statements the code just starts to look messy. I guess the transition call might be a bit neater if it was set up for call chaining

Answer (score 2):

Using coroutines might help here:

```
await = function(f)
    return function(...)
        local self = coroutine.running()
        f(..., {onComplete=function(...)
           coroutine.resume(self, ...)
        end})
        return coroutine.yield()
    end
end

await(transition.to)(obj)
await(transition.to)(obj)
if foo then
    await(transition.to)(obj)
else
    await(transition.to)(obj)
end
```

Or perhaps more generically, addressing the issue in the comments:

```
async_call = function(f)
    local self = coroutine.running()
    local is_async
    local results = nil
    local async_continue = function(...)
        if coroutine.running() ~= self then
            is_async = true
            coroutine.resume(self, ...)
        else
            is_async = false
            results = {...}
        end
    end
    f(async_continue)
    if is_async then
        return coroutine.yield()
    else
        return unpack(results)
    end
end

async_call(function(cont) transition.to(obj, {onComplete=cont}) end)
```

Comment: I think you've just exposed my shameful ignorance of Lua's coroutines. That's forced me to work through that chapter in Programming in Lua again!

Comment: @personalnadir: I make no claim that this will actually work. One thing that would cause it to fail would be if `f` actually invoked `onComplete` before returning.

Comment: Thanks for the examples though! It turns out that calling coroutine.yield from within the onComplete callback breaks the metamethod/C-call boundary. But I've written a simple simple stack of coroutines which gets me part way there based on your first example.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to define the callback as a global or upvalue and inject the upvalues the callback would need into it by wrapping the callback in another function:

```
function foo(upvalue)
    return function(...) -- thats the actual callback
        return print(upvalue, ...);
    end
end
```

Then you can just attach it as a callback like

```
transition.to(obj,{... onComplete=foo(somevar)})
```

The additional function call will however have some small impact on performance. On the other hand, if you have multiple similar callbacks, you could probably come up with some kind of code reuse.